# How do I watch a running program's STDOUT from a perl program that called it?

Tags: perl, file-io, io, exec, parent-child

We're trying to figure out how to run a java application from within a perl script but still be able to periodically read from the java app's STDOUT.

```
print "running dcmrcv.bat\n";

open my $fh_dcmrcv, "-|", 'z:\apps\dcm4che\dcm4che-2.0.26\bin\dcmrcv.bat \
  DCMRCV:11112 -dest z:\dcmrcv -journal z:\dcmrcv', 
  or die "could not execute dcmrcv: $!";

print "dcmrcv.bat started\n";
```

We wanted to be able to read from the filehandle, $fh_dmcrcv, every few minutes or perhaps by setting up an AnyEvent io trigger when there is activity on the filehandle.

However, when I try and read from the filehandle, it blocks if I use something like this:

```
foreach my $line (<$fh_dmcrcv>) {
  print $line;
}
```

We've tried several approaches, don't think we can use File::Tail, since it seems that module needs an actual file. The issue seems to be that $fh_dcmrcv is blocking us when we read from it, not really sure of the correct approach on how to achieve what we want.

**EDIT #1**

When we run our perl script we're seeing output like this:

```
Z:\projects\demo_2>process_files.pl
running dcmrcv.bat
dcmrcv.bat started
Start Server listening on port 11112
11:55:13,495 INFO   - Start listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:11112
```

The script, process_files.pl is emitting the msgs.:

```
running dcmrcv.bat
dcmrcv.bat started
```

The msgs. from the java program are:
    Start Server listening on port 11112
    11:55:13,495 INFO   - Start listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:11112

In this case we're echoing those out just for the sake of this question, really we want to periodically parse for certain msgs. and never echo any of them out.

Any insight is appreciated,

-Sam

Comment: Can you write the application output to a (temporary) file, and then use `File::Tail`?

Comment: We're trying to avoid that approach. We don't want to have to manage this file in terms of having to rotate it or trim it.

Comment: Have you tried using fctrl to set the descriptor to O_NONBLOCK?

Comment: When you say "it usually blocks", what behaviour exactly are you observing?

Comment: It always blocks, thanks I'll edit the question to rephrase that!

Comment: @frankc I looked into fcntl, which is what I think you meant. It appears that it isn't fully implemented on windows (fcntl is but fcntl(2) isn't), at least according to this [perlmonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?displaytype=print;node_id=65812;replies=1). I tried using fcntl anywhoo and I get the msg. **Your vendor has not defined Fcntl macro F_GETFL, ...**. So it would seem not to work on Windows.

Comment: @slm All right... and when you say "it always blocks", what is perl doing at this point? It is your conclusion that perl is blocking, but what do you actually observe?

Comment: @TLP my observation is that while attempting to read from the filehandle using a foreach/while loop it will stop after reading the last line of output available from the java program. I know it's getting stuck there because right after the loop, there is a print statement which never get's executed.

Comment: @slm Then that means that your batch script is still running, and perl is waiting for more. Or, your batch script prints a final line which does not end with newline. Try checking these points off and see if it helps. You may try setting `$/ = undef` to enable slurp mode. That could also help.

Comment: @TLP, http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/b/block.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most systems support a 4-argument `select` function (also packaged nicely in [`IO::Select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSelect)) that can tell you whether there is input waiting on sockethandle or pipehandle. In Windows, `select` is only supported on sockets, which leads to this byzantine solution:

1. Create a socket pair
2. Fork and run the command in a child process
3. In the child process, retrieve command output and write it to the socket
4. In the parent, use select and read operations on the socket as desired

Example:

```
use Socket;
use IO::Select;
use Time::HiRes;
$cmd = $^X . ' -MMath::BigInt -e "$_=1; '
       . 'print qq/$_!=/,Math::BigInt->new($_)->bfac(),qq/\n\n\n/'
       . ' for 4000..4100"';
socketpair A,B,AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,PF_UNSPEC;  # step 1
if (fork() == 0) {
    open my $fh, '-|', $cmd;                   # step 2
    while (<$fh>) {
        print B;                               # step 3
    }
    close $fh;
    exit $? >> 8;
}
$s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add(\*A);
for (;;) {
    if ($s->can_read(0.25)) {                  # step 4
        $line = <A>;
        print "Do something with command output: $line";
    } else {
        print "No output now. Could be doing something else ...\n";
        Time::HiRes::sleep(0.25);
    }
}
```

Are you sure you don't want to just write your command output to a temp file?

Comment: This 90% worked. I needed to add a `B->flush` right after the `print B` in order to get the socket's buffer to flush all output that was pending.

Comment: It pains me to accept this since it's a total hack in having to use tunnel IO through the Socket module but I haven't been able to come up with any other approach that works besides this. So congrats, this is the best answer that I could find.

Answer (score 2):

Use [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Select.pm) or four-argument `select()` to read when reading will not block.  **EDIT**: Nevermind, you're [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596803/how-do-i-do-a-non-blocking-ipc-read-on-windows), so this won't work.  One option: have an intermediary process read from this pipe and keep an intermediary file filled with just whatever tail-length you need of it. Bleh.

That said, the best way to read "every few minutes" from a pipe is to read from it every few seconds.

Comment: *read from it every few seconds* - this is especially true if your command produces a lot of output. The default buffer size on pipes and sockets can be quite small, and the command will block when it has no more room to write on the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading with this instead:

```
while (my $line = <$fh_dmcrcv>) {
   print $line;
}
```

regards

Comment: Tried variations of this and same result. Reading from the filehandle blocks the perl prog.

Comment: you're right. Probably you may want to check if your system supports opening a file with the non-blocking option, so read won't lock up if there's nothing to read from the file descriptor. You may find some hints in perl's sysopen